# RxJava2 conflate & multicast event stream

Tags: rx-java2

I've got an event source that emits a `Snapshot` followed by `Deltas` let's say it looks a bit like

```
Flowable.just("A", "1", "2", "3")
```

where "A" is the snapshot and "1", "2", "3" would be the updates.

I'd like the first subscriber to retrieve

```
"A", "1", "2", "3"
```

And the second subscriber (assuming it occurs between "2" and "3") to receive

```
"A".apply("1").apply("2"), "3"
```

So what I'm looking for is an operator that multicasts the stream but emits the conflated value from the first up until the next emission before the next emission for all subsequent subscribers.

Can someone point me into the right direction? Started writing a custom operator, but I feel like there's something easy I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked on it a bit more with my colleague and we've come up with the following

```
Flowable.just("A", "1", "2", "3")
 .scan(Tuple(empty, empty), (prev, update) -> build "snapshot" "last delta" tuple
 .skip(1)
 .replay(1) // replay tuple of "current snapshot" "latest delta"
 .refCount() 
 .scan(empty, (prev, update) -> empty == prev ? update.snapshot : update.delta)
 .skip(1)
```

works beautifully, and hopefully will be of use to the next person trying the same thing